# Speech Recognition duration setting issue in python

Tags: python, nlp, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I have an audio file in Wav format that I want to transcribe:

My code is:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
harvard = sr.AudioFile('speech_file.wav')
with harvard as source:
    try:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        #print("Done")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        exec()

r.recognize_google(audio)
```

I do receive an output:

```
Out[20]: 'thank you for calling my name is Denise who I have a pleasure speaking with hi my name is Mary Jane. Good afternoon Mary Jane I do have your account open with your email'
```

However, there is a lot more that is spoken after this. I think it only captures this part of the speech because there is a short pause after the word "email" is said in the audio file. I tried to set the duration, but i received an error:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
harvard = sr.AudioFile('speech_file.wav')
with harvard as source:
    try:
        audio = r.listen(source,duration = 200)
        #print("Done")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        exec()


r.recognize_google(audio)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-30fb65edc627>", line 5, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source,duration = 200)

TypeError: listen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duration'
```

What do I do so that my code transcribes the entire audio file and does not stop printing the text if there are pauses?

Comment: You get an error because the listen function does not have an argument named duration. See sourcecode for details: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py

Comment: Yes, im aware but what is the solution? I want it to transcribe the entire wav file

Comment: Without you providing the file, I can not reproduce the error and hence do: Nothing.

Comment: @NikolasRieble how do I upload the file here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `timeout` instead of `duration` like so:

```
audio = r.listen(source, timeout=2)
```

This means that the model will wait **two seconds at most** for a phrase to start before giving up and throwing an`speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError` exception. If `timeout=None`, there will be no wait which is your case.

### EDIT

All the function `recognize_google()` does is to call the google Speech API and get back the result. When I used the provided audio file, I got back the transcription of the first 30 seconds. That's due to the limitation of the free version of the Google speech API and has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: This producs the same ouput as before

Comment: You said there is a pause between the two sentences... Is it a long pause or a short one?

Comment: It is a short one after "email" but there could be other short ones or long ones during th entire audio. I just want my script to transcribe the entire audio file

Comment: Could you upload the file and provide the downloadable link ?

Comment: how do i upload the file? @Anwarvic

Comment: You can upload it to GoogleDrive for example and provide the downloadable link in your question

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxKKFbBh77UuCSLu3nV1YjxPO9AMlnGk/view?usp=sharing @Anwarvic. Here you go

Comment: Thanks Anwarvic, do you know of another open source API that has a larger limit or has no restriction?

Comment: Or how can I enroll for the paid version of this Google Speech API

Comment: Check the official website [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing).

Answer (score 1):

`r.listen(source)` will capture the first recognizable phrase. To extract every phrase from the audio file use `r.record(source)`

source: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/2.1.3/

Comment: Use back ticks \`r.listen(source)\` to format inline code. eg `r.listen(source)`