# Python Speech Recognition,Pyaudio not listening but giving this

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-to-text, pyaudio

I am trying to convert speech to text using speech recognition and pyaudio in python.It works fine while converting prerecorded audio file but when I record using microphone(external),it is not listening instead it is displaying this:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
```

Here's my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source:
  print('say somthing')
  audio = r.listen(source)
 
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Comment: i cannot even see the text of my speech

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpeechRecogniton module is too slow in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728785/speechrecogniton-module-is-too-slow-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this block of code. This works perfectly fine in my system even in the real time input.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
def myCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 5)  
    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
        print("you said: " + command)
        
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sorry, Cant understand, Please say again")
        command = myCommand()
    return command
```

Comment: can i hide those lines(ALSA lib etc..)

Comment: the recognition is poor.it displays completely different text

Comment: Well then there is the problem with your drivers. Because this works perfectly fine for me. Try updating the drivers.