# python speech_recognition start and stop

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a python program where you select a duration **`e.g 6`** and than start recording, using a for loop you will get a count down of how much time is left and than the recording stops and the audio will be saved.

**Code:**

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
while TimeLeft!=0:
    print(f'You have {TimeLeft} seconds left.')
    time.sleep(1)
    TimeLeft-=1
```

Running the code above will take from 50 to 150 seconds even though it should take 6, this is because `audio = r.listen(source)` takes a very long time to load. According to [SpeechRecogniton module is too slow in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728785/speechrecogniton-module-is-too-slow-in-python/63729119#63729119) I should use `phrase_time_limit` or `timeout` for `.listen` to take exactly 6 seconds to load, if I use that method how will i be able to make a countdown?

> Note that the code i showed in the question is inside a `pygame` loop.

Comment: `r.listen()` is blocking code so you can't display a countdown while it blocks in sync code. Your options are: Starting a thread to display the countdown or to research if there's a non-blocking way to collect the audio.

Comment: @576i i did do a lots of research and the most useful thing i found was the first thing that came up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728785/speechrecogniton-module-is-too-slow-in-python/63729119#63729119

Comment: You can use another thread to print out the remaining seconds, meanwhile add the timeout to the listen function.

Comment: @Jason Pan im not sure how i could use a thread mid of code, the only way i use it is for mid code But not sure how you can do it in mid code. Note that the code i showed in the question is inside a `pygame` loop. Sorry i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two thread to do listen and count parallelly. You also need a synchronization such as threading.Event to notify the counting thread to stop.

```py
import threading
import time

import speech_recognition as sr


def inside_code():

    e = threading.Event()

    def f1():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source, 5)
        e.set()

    def f2():
        TimeLeft = 5

        while not e.is_set() and TimeLeft != 0:
            print(f'You have {TimeLeft} seconds left.')
            time.sleep(1)
            TimeLeft -= 1

    thread_list = [threading.Thread(target=f1), threading.Thread(target=f2)]
    for t in thread_list:
        t.start()
    for t in thread_list:
        t.join()


inside_code()
```